# How can I bulk upload and transform relational data to aggregates in RavenDB?

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

I'm trying to get my head around how to do efficient bulk inserts of relational data into RavenDB, particularly where converting from relational data to aggregates.

Let's say we have two dump files of two tables: `Orders` and `OrderItems`. They're too big to load into memory, so I read them as streams. I can read through each table and create a document in RavenDB corresponding to each row. I can do this as bulk operations using [batched requests](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-http-batching-2). Easy and efficient so far.

Then I want to transform this on the server, getting rid of the `OrderItems` and integrating them in to their parent `Order` documents. How can I do this without thousands of roundtrips?

The answer seems to lie somewhere between [set-based updates](http://ravendb.net/documentation/set-based), [live projections](http://ayende.com/blog/4661/ravendb-live-projections-or-how-to-do-joins-in-a-non-relational-database) and [denormalized updates](http://ravendb.net/faq/denormalized-updates), but I don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to do this with [denormalised updates](http://ravendb.net/faq/denormalized-updates) and [set-based updates](http://ravendb.net/documentation/set-based). Take a look at the [PATCH API](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates) to see what it offers. Although you only need the set-based updates if you plan on updating several docs at once, you can just patch against a know doc directly using the PATCH api.

Live projections will only help you when you are getting the results of a query/index, they don't change the docs themselves, only what is returned from the server to the client.

However I'd recommend that if possible you combine a Order and the corresponding OrderItems in-memory before you send them to RavenDB. You could still stream the data from the dump files, just use some caching if needed. This will be the simplest option.

**Updated**
I've made some [sample code](http://gist.github.com/990623) that shows how to do this. This patches the `Comments` array/list within a particular `Post` doc, in this case "Posts/1"

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't see how to patch update Orders using data from other documents (effectively using a nested loop join).

And I can't see how to combine the full Order before uploading, because each Order's order items are buried deep within the `OrderItems` dump. I would need some sort of database to cross-reference the two. I could use a SQL database to do this, but that sort of defeats the object of going NoSQL!

Comment: Take a look at the section "Operating on Arrays" here http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-http-api-patch. You need to construct a new PatchRequest{...} with the type "add" to add the OrderItems into the relevant Order doc.

Comment: That would let me insert the *same* value into an array in every Order document. Obviously I need to insert different values into each array based on a lookup. I can't see how the PATCH command lets me do that.

Comment: Take a look at the gist here https://gist.github.com/990623, I think it shows what you're trying to do. The Post is created with an empty list of comments and then the comments are then patched by adding items to the array. This sample is a modified version of the unit test "CanAddValuesToList()" from here https://github.com/mattwarren/ravendb-FacetedSearch/blob/master/Raven.Tests/Bugs/Patching.cs

Comment: That sample patches ONE post document (i.e. "posts/1") and inserts three specific comments into it. That's no good - there isn't ONE document to update - there are thousands of them.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, sorry I mis-understood your original question. So you need to use the same PatchRequest(..) as the code, but do the patching using a set-based operation. So you'll be doing a patch but using an index to determine which docs to apply the patch to.

Comment: If this doesn't cover it you'll need to just use the "single doc" patch approach, but issue it multiple time with the correct key for each doc you want to patch. Unfortunately the RavenDB patching API doesn't cover every scenario, so doing it in-memory and then sending the complete Order/OrderItems doc to the server might be your only option.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is that you take a look at the RavenDB ETL example here https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/tree/master/ETL. This imports the StackOverflow data dump in 2 passes. It adds the questions and then creates the patches necessary to add the comments. But I think it stores alot of data on disk to make this possible.

Comment: Thanks - that looks like a very interesting product to take a look at, so I'll do that later.

Comment: He seems to load all the child records into memory to process them. E.g. in `AddCommentsToPost` he uses `rows.GroupBy(row => row["PostId"])` over all the rows (GroupBy will load the whole thing into memory). If Ayende isn't doing the whole thing using Raven, I guess it can't be done using Raven. That said, I think the best approach *is* to get the documents aggregated before sending to Raven.